# mongoDB changing existing JSON format

Tags: json, mongodb, format

I have a collection that holds Person attributes.First i added persons to mongodb with fieldnames like this :

```
{FirstName,LastName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumbertype,Email}
```

But now i need to change the format of JSON like this :

```
{FirstName,LastName,{AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City},{PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberType},{EmailAddress}}.
```

So,some of the fields should be an attributes of an object.
Is there any simple way to do this?Like a command or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way, assuming you can spare iterating your users collection, which may be very slow depending on how many documents in the collection, but simple altogether:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(d) {
    var address = {
        AddressLine1 : d.AddressLine1,
        AddressLine2 : d.AddressLine2,
        City : d.City
    }
    delete(d.AddressLine1)
    delete(d.AddressLine2)
    delete(d.City)
    d.Address = address
    db.users.save(d)
})
```

Missed the part where you also want to embed the phone portions, but the principle is the same